# Syntax of out-of-class definition of a template member function of a template class

Tags: c++, syntax

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class mindF_ck
{
    template<typename C>
    inline bool ouch(C & c_in);    
};
```

How do I define the signature for `ouch` out-of-class ? I send a query to my brain but it keeps coming up blank ;)

Comment: That class name definitely worth my vote :))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
template<typename A, typename B>
template<typename C>
bool mindf_uck<A,B>::ouch(C & c_in) {
}
```

Comment: You forgot the return type :)

Is the `<C>` in `ouch<C>` strictly required?

Comment: Was about to edit it in, when I noticed some else was already fiddeling with it, thx David ;-)

Comment: @Lstor: You are right, the <C> I had behind ouch is not required. I think it may very well be even an error

Comment: Mine was technically a bit more correct initially, since I had `bool` and did not have `ouch<C>` - but his was a tad faster than mine ;)

Comment: actually yours appeared first on my screen :D, make me wonder if SO has moved away from SQL SERVER to an "eventually consistant" distributed database.

Answer (score 7):

```
template <typename A, typename B>
  template <typename C>
bool mindf_ck<A, B>::ouch(C& c_in) {
    // ... code ...
}
```