# Eigen templated function correct declaration

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I'm trying to create a templated Eigen function, but apparently I fail to get the correct structure. I have:

*Utils.hpp*

```
#pragma once

#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <vector>

class Utils
{
public:
    Utils(){};
    ~Utils(){};
    
    template <typename Derived>
    void removeZeroRows(Eigen::EigenBase<Derived> &M, double epsilon);
};
    
#include "Utils.tpl"
```

*Utils.tpl*

```
template <typename Derived>
void removeZeroRows(Eigen::EigenBase<Derived> &M, double epsilon)
{

    long asls = M.rows();
    long aslz = {};
    for (long i = 0; i < asls; i++)
    {
        if (M.row(i).isZero(epsilon))
            aslz++;
    }
    asls = asls - aslz;

    Eigen::EigenBase<Derived> MNZ(asls, M.cols());

    for (long i = 0, j = 0; i < asls; i++)
    {
        if (!M.row(i).isZero(epsilon))
        {
            MNZ.row(j) = M.row(i);
            j++;
        }
    }

    M = MNZ;
};
```

invoked with:

```
VectorXi STC;
STC = ST;
utils->removeZeroRows(STC, epsilon);

and

MatrixXd ECL;
ECL.resize(size, 3);
ECL.setZero();

utils->removeZeroRows(ECL, epsilon);
```

That gives an error while building:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "void Utils::removeZeroRows<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >(Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >&, double)", referenced from:
      Common::AlignEdgestoAxis(Mesh&, bool)::$_0::operator()(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>&, Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>&, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>&) const in AlignEdgestoAxis.cpp.o
  "void Utils::removeZeroRows<Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >(Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >&, double)", referenced from:
      Common::AlignEdgestoAxis(Mesh&, bool)::$_0::operator()(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>&, Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>&, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>&) const in AlignEdgestoAxis.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Can someone decipher it? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

(totally idiotic) mostly, code, filler, mostly, code, filler, mostly, code, filler, mostly, code, filler, mostly, code, filler, mostly, code, filler...

Comment: In Utils.tpl write `template <typename Derived> void Utils::removeZeroRows(Eigen::EigenBase<Derived> &M, double epsilon)`, otherwise you define a new independent function template.

Comment: Actually, couldn't find a duplicate for the trivial case. Here is one for a slightly more complicated case (if the class itself is also a template): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895179/syntax-of-out-of-class-definition-of-a-template-member-function-of-a-template-cl (I did not search very long, though)

Comment: Did that. With Utils::removeZeroRows i get a swathe of errors like ../../../src/common/Utils.tpl:83:15: error: no member named 'row' in 'Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >'
        if (M.row(i).isZero(epsilon)) showing it apparently doesn't recognize eigen structure...

Comment: That's a completely unrelated problem. Try `Eigen::DenseBase` or `Eigen::MatrixBase` instead of `Eigen::EigenBase` and replace `Eigen::EigenBase<Derived> MNZ` by, e.g., `typename Derived::Plaintype MNZ`

Comment: @chtz I think you might mean ```Derived::PlainObject```?
That would at least be my advice, to change this line
```Eigen::EigenBase<Derived> MNZ(asls, M.cols());``` to
```Derived::PlainObject MNZ(asls, M.cols());```

Comment: @RL-S, yes `Derived::PlainObject` is correct (I just wrote this from memory, and sometimes forget the name of that typedef). But I think a leading `typename` is still necessary.